# Short URL in content

Tags: shortlink

One of our clients is looking to use shortURL's in their content posts. Does anyone know if it's possible to setup shortURL's in the content of posts? I know bit.ly offers a shortURL for the post url but I don't know if they accept it as well for the content of a post.

Comment: please follow link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-custom-url-shortener-for-publicize

Comment: @AmitBera This is only for the POSTURL instead of content url's.